# Proof, that B^T B is a regular matrix, when B is a set of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

im interested in following proof:
Let $$B = [b_1, ... b_m] \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$$ be a matrix, that consists of m independent basis vectors $$b_i$$ and m<n. Why is it, that $$B^TB$$ is a regular matrix?
Would be very glad, if anybody can help me with this. Thx!

Answer (score -1):

Since $\|v\|^2=v^Tv$ for any vector $v$, we have
$$B^TBx=0\ \implies\ \|Bx\|^2 =x^TB^TBx =0\ \implies\ Bx=0$$
which implies $x=0$ because the columns of $B$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Please read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: Well, most probably this was indeed answered here (multiple times), however the linked question is not an exact duplicate of this one.